# how to get cmsamplebuffer data to avformate_open_input() function in FFMpeg?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, streaming, cmsamplebuffer

i want to stream apple mobile camera to a UDP port using FFMPEG. so far i have already done  it from a video file. but now i want to do it live from apple mobile camera. 
some body can give me some clue for this. my head is spining for this solution?
Please help me.